# Teradata 15: Failure 7545 Identity Column is over its limit

Tags: sql, teradata

I got this Teradata failure 7545 Identity Column is over its limit, but I am only insert a few hundreds records and i have already change data type from INT to BIGINT.

Here is my create table syntax, I am really puzzled why Teradata was not happy?

```
CREATE  TABLE LOCATION
(        LOCATION_ID          BIGINT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH  1 INCREMENT BY 1 MAXVALUE     1000000)  ,
     ....
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3):

Your definition defaults to `NO CYCLE` and `MAXVALUE` is set to `1000000`, so it doesn't matter if you use an `INT` or `BIGINT`, the maximum number is 1,000,000.

Teradata assigns an IDENTITY in parallel, i.e. it's each AMP/PE requests a range of numbers based on the `dbscontrol` parameter `IdCol Batch Size`, so 1,000,000 will be reached way before you actually insert a million rows.

Remove the `MAXVALUE`, but keep the BIGINT, use INT only if need to store up to a few million rows...

Comment: The following is what worked for me.  I did not initially realize what was meant by removing MAXVALUE, so figured that I'd share.  `row_id BIGINT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
(START WITH 1 
INCREMENT BY 1
NO CYCLE),`

Answer (score 0):

Try with ALWAYS and  NO CYCLE instead of generate by default...
Also check for the IdCol Batch Size in your DBSCONTROL parameter 27.
Like in my case it was 10k so , try to increase it and then try.

27. IdCol Batch Size               = 10000

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that  worked:

I increased the max value to 100 million.

The reason is that each AMP gets a 100,000 range of numbers. I have 72 AMPs in my 2750 appliance, so a minimum max value is 7.2 million. When my definition of the max identity column value exceeds 7.2 million, it worked.