# Teradata SQL: how to do generated by default identity insert without multiple amps running up the increment triggering error 7545?

Tags: sql, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I have a table with a smallint identity column generated by default:

```
MyIdColumn smallint generated by default as identity (start with 1 increment by 1)
```

The column is expected to be 2 or 3 digits at most, hence the smallint.

I want to do a single row insert; unfortunately when I insert the single row I get error 7545 "numbering for identity column is over its limit". Explain shows that Teradata is doing an all-AMPs retrieve & all-AMPs merge, and a search turns up that on Teradata the many thousands of AMPs are somehow requesting and therefore [running up the next identity value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33312682/teradata-15-failure-7545-identity-column-is-over-its-limit) (which would I suppose cap out at 32,767).

What are my options here to get this working? Is there a query hint I can specify to tell Teradata just to run the 1-row insert on one AMP and not run up the increment? Do I really need to specify a bigint or other larger data type for what in practice is merely 2 or 3 digit number just to accommodate Teradata?

Comment: Identity column  is NOT a sequence. For INSERT/SELECT each AMP tries to obtain a block  of potential identity column values (by default 10000) before inserting any rows. https://docs.teradata.com/reader/EicR5yFgCYpUoOw_lp74Yg/w_cHsCimKlyWxAGrkmByYQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try INTEGER datatype which will support MAX value 2,147,483,647 to MIN value -2,147,483,647

If required create new table and reload the data in new table with below changes

MyIdColumn INTEGER generated by default as identity (start with 1 increment by 1)

Comment: Ultimately I just changed from smallint to a larger data type as suggested. It would have been nice to keep smallint, but it was more useful to have a working identity column.